# My bike tire just started rubbing against the frame. Please help me fix it

Tags: tire

[image]

the problem is the back tire just started rubbing against the frame. this literally happened 30 min ago. please help me fix it!!

Comment: By the way: PLEASE lube your chain...

Comment: You're loosing a pedal reflector on the bike's right pedal.  Suggest you clip that back into place.

Comment: Most likely the axle as slipped in the slots, due to a loose fixing bolt.  The other major possibility is something (like a broken spoke) that made the wheel go out of true.

Comment: As a first step, have you tried simply pushing the wheel back in to place? What happens when you try this may give you some clues as to what is wrong...

Answer (score 13):

I'm going to guess that the wheel slipped in the dropouts (where the wheel's axle enters the frame).

Loosen the nuts that hold the wheel's axle in the frame. Push the wheel back into the dropouts all the way (depending on the frame, you might not do all the way; the wheel should be sufficiently in the dropouts). Check that the wheel is centered. Then, tighten the nuts.

Comment: If the bike has rim brakes, I sometimes clamp or tie the handlebar brake lever down.  Then I tighten up the right-side wheel nut as far back up the dropout as it goes.  The left-side dropout on many bikes is a lot deeper and so the wheel nut on that side is NOT all the way back.  So kneeling on the left side of the bike I use my left hand to hold the tyre evenly between the chainstays and do up the axle nut with the right hand.  Some bikes are super-fiddly and other bikes are really easy to get right.

Comment: Good point. If you have vertical dropouts, its all the way. If its horizontal, betterf rames have an adjuster screw thing that lets you set it where you want.

Answer (score -7):

or it just could be that you need to tighten your bearings and you have to take the tire off then the tube and the bearings should be on your rim that's what a bike shop told me to do cause my bike does it also.

Comment: If the bike shop said you have bearings on your rim you need a new bike shop

Comment: If the inner nut was loose, the wheel would be sloppy and not just skewed to one side.

Comment: I am suspicious that the answer is an exercise in trolling.